# Writing regular expression without a recursive rule

Tags: regex, recursion

I need to write a regular expression rule where the expressions I have doesn't have a recursive rule.

For example, if I need to write an expression where I can have any number of a's, b's, c's, and d's but not have any a's and d's immediately following any b's. a's and d's can appear later in the string though.

Here are all the rules I can use:
[image: rules]
Tried this: `(a|d)* (c|b)* c* (a|d)*`. However, as you can see, I would need to keep repeating to make this work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of accepted words and rejected words?

Comment: @stribizhev he does not ask about posix regex but regular expression

Comment: I can only use what you see in the picture. So I can't use the expression you used above. So, for example, just writing `a` would only one a. Writing `a*` could be `{ Epsilon, a, aa, aaa, aaaa...}`. Something like `ax*` would be like `{ax, axx, axxxxxx, ...}`.

Comment: What about [this one](https://regex101.com/r/lN0zK1/2)? I do not know if you can or intend to use anchors though.

Comment: Thanks, but you're right. I can't use `$,^`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rephrase the question.

> I can have any number of a's, b's, c's, and d's but not have any a's and d's following any b's.

In other words, you can have `(a|c|d)` any number of times, but <strike>when</strike> if a `b` appears, then any number of `(b|c)`: so, `(a|c|d)* (b (b|c)*) | ɛ)`.

It is formally equal to `(a|c|d)* (b|c)*` (you might want to figure out why), but in practice, despite being shorter, this one is subject to catastrophic failure when evaluated by the common regexp algorithms.

(If you want to test it on computational/practical regexps, as opposed to theoretical ones, it translates to `[acd]*(?:b[bc]*)?`.)

EDIT: Yeah, misread the question. "immediately following" might have been a good word choice. How about...

```
(a|c|d|b+c)*(b|ɛ)
(?:[acd]|(?:b+c))*b?
```

Explaining the logic here, you can use any of the letters, but if you use `b`, you can go on with any number of `b`s but when you tire of that the next one needs to be a `c` (the only remaining one if you stopped `b`-ing and can't do `a` or `c`). Then it's back to the usual programme. At the end, you can have a `b` that is not necessarily followed by anything.

Comment: How does that add any number of a's and d's after? For example, you can have `abbbbcadadbca`.

Comment: @Maru: Ooh, I misread! So, it blocks only *immediately following* `b`... Okay.

Comment: If I understand correctly, doesn't this have same problem as above? If you choose b then nothing, it loops back to beginning and you choose a or d again.

Comment: @Maru: Bleeh, I said it correctly in the explanation then kitten up in the code. Fixing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can build automata and convert it into regular expression.
Since a and d cannot be after b:

[image]

And here only stated `acd` and `b` are accepted. START can also be accepted if you accept empty word.

So you can start with `(a|c|d)`. It can repeat itself without changing state so `(a|c|d)*`. From state b you can go with `b*` OR one `c` - this gives `b*|c` -> `(b(b*|c))`. This gives in total `(((a|c|d)*)|(b(b*|c)))*`

Comment: Nitpick: `b|(b|c)` is not correct - because it could give you `bb`, then you get again the unrestricted `a|c|d` choice following the second `b`.

Comment: There is no `b|(b|c)`. Did you mean `b(b|c)` ?

Comment: Doesn't this allow `aabba`? It repeats `(a|c|d)` then you can pick `bb` because of the OR. Then go back to a or d? Maybe I'm not understanding the logic.

Comment: Right - c should be out of scope and escape regex since state is changing. Post updated

Comment: I think your updated code still has the same logical error. Because of `(b*|c)`, a `c` can never be chosen. Thank you for all the help by the way. I learned a lot from this.

Comment: If we start from `a` then choose `bb`, it loops back to beginning because of `*` at end. At this point, we can choose `a or d` again. Am I not getting it?

Comment: @Maru you're right - out of parenthesis star makes start again from abc so ba would be possible. I need to figure it out since * out of scope is required to since we can have (a|b|c) after abbc